# Where is the documentation for elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.indices.create()?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

One can create an index in Elasticsearch with this line of code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
es.indices.create(index = "new_index")
```

But where is the documentation for the `indices.create` function? I've looked [here](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#indices) but all I found was `elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.create`. Is it the same somehow? If so, why is it said to be located at `elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.create` rather than `elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.indices.create`?

Answer (score 2):

I found out the answer myself. `elasticsearch.Elasticsearch()` returns an object which has a property `indices`, which is an instance of `IndicesClient`. Thus, `elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.create` is the same function as the one I am calling in my code snippet.